# funciones encadenadas en c

Tags: c

En estructuras o clases de c++ se pueden encadenar funciones si estas devuelven una referencia al objecto tal que así funcion1().funcion2().funcion3()...
En c habría alguna manera de hacer esto? Tal vez un puntero a una función?
Solo se me ha ocurrido hacer esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct date
{
    unsigned day;
    struct date *(*func_print)(struct date*);
     struct date *(*func_assign)(struct date*,unsigned);
};

struct date *create_date(void)
{
    struct date *obj = malloc(sizeof(struct date));
    return obj ? obj : NULL;
}

struct date *assign(struct date *this, unsigned value){
    this->day = value;
    return this;
}
struct date* print(struct date *this){
    printf("%d\n",this->day);
    return this;
}

int main()
{
    struct date *my = create_date();    
    my->func_print = print;
    my->func_assign = assign;
    my->func_assign(my,20)->func_print(my);

    free(my);

}
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Tu código es correcto. ¿ Quieres **no tener que usar `->`** ?

Comment: @Trauma quería una forma mas clara de hacerlo si es posible

Answer (score 0):

Las funciones encadenadas son realmente útiles en lenguajes de programación orientados a objetos (como C++, Java, C#, etc), debido que los objetos almacenan y mantienen un estado (`this`) entre las distintas llamadas a métodos (Pasándoles `this` a través de mecanismos internos del lenguaje y que son transparentes para el programador). Sin embargo, C NO es orientado a objetos, entonces no tiene caso hacer este tipo de cosas. Si observas tu código, la variable `my` es la que almacena y mantiene el estado entre las distintas llamadas a función, eso esta bien, pero requerir acceder a campos de una estructura que almacena los punteros a funciones para luego llamarlas sin esto ser estrictamente requerido resulta en accesos a memoria innecesarios.